# Как добавить поле в большую таблицу PostgreSQL без блокировки?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица вот такого вида:

```
create table email_stats (
    id bigserial primary key,
    mailing_list_id int not null,
    sended_date timestamp not null,
    emails_send bigint not null default 0,
    emails_clicks bigint not null default 0
);
```

Теперь в неё необходимо добавить новое поле. Так-то задача простая,

```
alter table email_stats 
    add column emails_paid_clicks bigint not null default 0;
```

Вот только проблема: табличка уже размером в несколько десятков гигабайт и этот `alter table` блокирует всю запись в таблицу на длительное время.

Как можно добавить поле без простоя системы?

PS: странно, но не нашёл такого распространённого вопроса здесь

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Если вы счастливый пользователь PostgreSQL 11 или новее (но не надо бета-версии в рабочие проекты ставить) - то все хитрые фокусы теперь спрятаны внутри и достаточно напрямую сделать `alter table`:

```
set statement_timeout to '1s';
alter table email_stats 
    add column emails_paid_clicks bigint not null default 0;
```

[Принятый в postgresql 11 патч](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/17/1401/) позволяет больше не копировать всю таблицу заново при добавлении нового поля со значением по-умолчанию. И проблему с длительным блокированием таблицы может представлять только ситуация, когда `alter table` вынужден ждать получение эксклюзивной блокировки из-за того что эту блокировку удерживают какие-то другие транзакции. Потому имеет смысл ставить небольшой `statement_timeout` и повторять попытки выполнения `alter table`.

---

Если же у вас postgresql версии ниже 11, то всё не так просто. В указанном запросе

```
alter table email_stats 
    add column emails_paid_clicks bigint not null default 0;
```

к *длительной* блокировке таблицы приводит `default 0`. PostgreSQL берёт блокировку на таблицу и начинает перебирать все записи в таблице проставлять на уровне данных и только после этого отпустит блокировку. А вот если вставлять по-умолчанию `NULL` - то PostgreSQL обновит только метаданные таблицы в служебном каталоге, что очень быстро, но это не то что требуется.

Поэтому внести желаемое изменение возможно, но выглядеть оно будет совсем не так, а в много действий.

### Начинаем аккуратно вносить изменение

Сначала добавляем новое поле как null по-умолчанию - это быстро, только изменить метаданные таблицы. Затем ставим желаемое значение по-умолчанию - это значение уже будет применяться для новых вставляемых строк.

```
begin;
set local statement_timeout = '1s';
alter table email_stats 
    add column emails_paid_clicks bigint;
alter table email_stats 
    alter column emails_paid_clicks set default 0;
commit;
```

Отдельного пояснения заслуживает зачем я изменил `statement_timeout` в транзакции. Эта настройка ограничивает максимальное время выполнения запроса. Этот `alter table` всё равно требует блокировку на таблицу, хоть и на короткое время и здесь есть скрытые грабли: что если `alter table` не может взять блокировку из-за какой-то другой выполняемой транзакции? Например, простой `insert` в другой транзакции не позволит взять блокировку для изменения структуры. Но при этом запущенный `alter table` уже заблокирует все последующие пишущие запросы к этой таблице. Короткий `statement_timeout` быстро убьёт `alter table` и сервис продолжит работу. А попытку добавить поле можно безболезненно повторить чуть позже пока это в итоге не удастся.

Есть ещё интересная грабля, что явное указание `default null` в `alter table` в каких-то случаях может считаться значением `NULL` не эквивалентного типа данных и база начинать опять же таблицу переписывать. Чтобы не ловить эту редкую граблю лучше не указывать `default null` в явном виде, а оставить тот который подразумевается самим `add column`. По-умолчанию там `NULL` и предполагается.

### Поле добавили, теперь default в данных

Длительный процесс, необходимо запросами

```
update email_stats 
    set emails_paid_clicks = default 
    where emails_paid_clicks is null 
        and /* следующий кусочек данных */
```

проставить желаемое значение в имеющихся данных таблицы. Обновлять данные необходимо кусочками (для чего в запросе оставил открытое условие), делая паузы между обновлениями, следить за отставанием репликации (если такая есть) и за процессами autovacuum. Есть несколько подходов по самому обновлению, более простой будет обновлять по первичному или любому уникальному ключу. Берём любой язык программирования или сценариев по своему вкусу и делаем что-то такое:

```
$current_id = (select min(id) from email_stats)
$maxid = (select max(id) from email_stats)

while ($current_id < $maxid) {
    $batch_to = $current_id + 10000 // максимальный размер пачки для одного обновления
    update email_stats 
        set emails_paid_clicks = default 
        where emails_paid_clicks is null 
            and id >= $current_id and id < $batch_to

    $current_id = $batch_to
    sleep(5) -- задержка между обновлениями чтобы меньше мешать сервису
}
```

Во время выполнения такого скрипта можно изредка делать `vacuum email_stats` чтобы табличка не сильно увеличивалась в размерах. Особенно если `autovacuum` настроен недостаточно агрессивно и не успевает прибирать за скриптом.

Размер одного обновления и величину паузы между обновлениями нужно подбирать под профиль нагрузки конкретного сервиса. Маленькие обновления и большие паузы не будут никому мешать, но просто выполняться скрипт будет очень долго.

Пример запроса не самый эффективный, время его выполнения будет сильно плавать от пропусков id в данных и потому что данные скорей всего будут в разных страничках памяти, зато он простой и можно легко настраивать максимальный размер для одного обновления.

Из подводных камней на этом этапе: гораздо проще поймать `deadlock`, подравшись с приложением за обновление строк если приложение захочет обновить несколько строк из той же самой пачки, но в другом порядке. Можно поставить соединению, в котором работает скрипт этого обновления настройку `deadlock_timeout = 100ms`, тогда при взаимоблокировке будет как правило убиваться наш скрипт, а не полезная транзакция приложения.

### Ставим `not null`

Теперь у нас в таблице не должно быть null значений в добавленном поле, можно проставить not null.

```
alter table email_stats alter column emails_paid_clicks set not null;
```

Этот запрос к сожалению поставит блокировку на запись. Но время выполнения куда меньше чем на обновление всей таблицы с перезаписью значения по умолчанию.

С минимальной блокировкой записи придётся отказаться от родного `not null` свойства, зато [можно добавить](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42071253) `check` ограничение с аналогичным свойством. Сначала добавляем ограничение с указанием `not valid` (аналогично со `statement timeout` для транзакции)

```
begin;
set local statement_timeout = '1s';
alter table email_stats 
     add constraint emails_paid_clicks_not_null 
     check (emails_paid_clicks is not null) not valid;
commit;
```

Затем в другой транзакции уже без `statement_timeout`

```
alter table email_stats validate constraint emails_paid_clicks_not_null;
```

Проверка ограничения не заблокирует запись.

Для postgresql 11 и новее вся эта инструкция сильно короче стала, но для красоты дополню ещё немного, не зря же старался, [патч писал](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/22/1389/). Начиная с postgresql 12 `alter table set not null` может пропустить проверку данных в таблице, если имеющихся ограничений хватает чтобы поверить в отсутствие `NULL` в этом поле. Да, я как раз говорю про `check constraint` который я только что описал как создавать без долгой блокировки. После того, как ограничение прошло `validate constraint` можно вызвать `set not null` и удалить более ненужный `check`. Для этого всё равно потребуется блокировка таблицы, но теперь уже короткая.

```
begin;
set local statement_timeout = '1s';
alter table email_stats alter column emails_paid_clicks set not null;
alter table email_stats 
     drop constraint emails_paid_clicks_not_null;
commit;
```

### Готово

Всё, поле добавлено

---

Кстати, имеет смысл подумать, не использовать ли по-умолчанию именно NULL. Такое поле не только сильно проще добавляется, но и существенно компактнее хранится. Значение NULL - это один бит в битовой маске заголовка строки, Значение 0 типа bigint - уже занимает 8 байт.

Comment: Просто шикарный комментарий! Это уже не ответ, а мини-справочник по подобным действиям в больших таблицах. Спасибо!

Comment: Круто! Мне сразу захотелось добавить пару колонок в свои таблицы, только повода пока нет!