# Секционирование существующей таблицы PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Есть есть одна таблица на 50+ гигов. По мере увеличения объема информации увеличивается и время отработки запросов(используем PostgreSQL 11.2, запросы идут из DjangoORM). Погуглив понял что для нас секционирование будет хорошим решением, так как львиная доля запросов идет по последним данным (месяц-два). Поразмыслив решил сделать секционирование по месяцам. Я в этой теме совсем новичок, поэтому прощу совета тут. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать это наиболее эффективно и без какого-либо ущерба(ежедневно в базу вносятся новые данные в произвольное время).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прежде чем перейти к сути, два момента:

- "используем PostgreSQL 11.**2**" - это очень плохо. Обновляйтесь до актуального minor (11.9 на момент написания). За прошедшие вот уже полтора года было исправлено много ошибок и нет совсем никакого смысла в том чтобы их собирать самостоятельно.
- 50гб табличка это не много. Скорей всего ваша проблема в чём-то другом. В самих запросах, индексах, настройках СУБД или просто в железе.

---

Принимаемая во внимание конкретика для ответа:

- существует таблица `measurements`, которую хотим партицировать для новых данных по месяцам по полю `created_at timestamp not null`, заполняемом в текущую датавремя
- postgresql 10 или новее для использования штатного декларативного партицирования
- до следующей границы месяца база дотянет и миграция производится в спокойном контролируемом режиме

---

### Подготовка

Для партицирования по месяцам проще всего историческую таблицу просто подключить как раздел исторических данных.

Сначала создаём новую головную партицированную таблицу идентичной структуры под каким-нибудь новым именем:

```
create table tablename_parthead (/*....*/) partition by range (created_at);
```

И раздел с данными на будущее:

```
create table measurements_202009 partition of measurements_parthead for values from ('2020-09-01') to ('2020-10-01');
```

Чтобы не устраивать длительный даунтайм сервиса, немного подготовим нашу таблицу с данными:

```
begin;
set local statement_timeout to '1s';
alter table measurements add constraint measurements_partbound_check check (created_at < '2020-09-01' and created_at is not null) not valid;
commit;

alter table measurements validate constraint measurements_partbound_check ;
```

Что за пляски со `statement_timeout` и `not valid` лучше [читайте отдельно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/721986/203622). Это фокус DBA чтобы не устраивать долгий exclusive лок живой таблицы если кто-то мешает его взять быстро.

Если `validate constraint` даёт ошибки - то проверяйте ваши данные. Важно, что поле, по которому партицируется таблица, должно быть `not null`.

Обратите внимание, что теперь вы должны завершить всю миграцию до наступления даты `2020-09-01` либо удалить ограничение и начать сначала:

```
alter table measurements drop constraint measurements_partbound_check ;
```

Этот `check` не даст вставить в таблицу строки с created_at больше указанной даты.

### Час Х

```
begin;
set statement_timeout to '1s';
alter table measurements rename to measurements_archive;
alter table measurements_parthead rename to measurements;
alter table measurements attach partition measurements_archive for values from (MINVALUE) to ('2020-09-01');
commit;
```

На этом всё. Теперь ваша таблица `measurements` является партицированной за две блокировки менее секунды длительностью. Данные до `2020-09-01` продолжат писаться фактически в старую таблицу, затем начнут писаться в новую.

---

Если вы хотите именно разрезать имеющующуяся таблицу с данными на части - вам лучше этого не хотеть =) Возможно, но для этого потребуется подготовить рядом под отличающимися именами новые таблицы под данные, скопировать туда данные (`insert .. select ...`, например), каким-либо образом проконтролировать что вы меняете данные в старой большой таблице и в новых разделах одновременно (триггером, например), затем схожими alter table заменить старую большую таблицу на новые разделы поменьше.

Comment: 2ndQuadrant blog: [Partitioning a large table without a long-running lock](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/partitioning-a-large-table-without-a-long-running-lock/)