# Партиция с существующей таблицы

Tags: postgresql, partition

Есть очень большая таблица. Хочу ускорить селект путем разделения ее на партиции, а точнее существующую таблицу перевести в архивную партицию, а для новых записей создавать свежие партиции. Но проблема в том, что система высоконагруженная и все эти изменения нужно проводить за максимально короткий лок данных. Думал, если партиции разделать по индексному значению это поможет, но практика показала что нет. Может кто в курсе самого оптимального решения?

Answer (score 1):

> точнее существующую таблицу перевести в архивную партицию, а для новых записей создавать свежие партиции

Такое реально сделать за секундный даунтайм весьма просто. Ключевая хитрость - необходим check constraint, подходящий для условия партицирования.

Предположим, что мы говорим о табличке вида

```
CREATE TABLE measurement (
     id bigserial NOT NULL primary key,
     created_at timestamp without time zone default now(),
     data bigint NOT NULL
);
```

Которую хотим партицировать по месяцам по полю `created_at`.

Для этого нужно:

1. удостовериться, что поле партицирования исключает значения NULL: (пояснения, пожалуй, не буду перепечатывать [из другого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/721986/203622))

```
begin;
set local statement_timeout = '1s';
alter table measurement 
    add constraint measurement_created_at_not_null 
    check (created_at is not null) not valid;
commit;
alter table measurement validate constraint measurement_created_at_not_null;
```

для версии postgresql начиная с 12 можно поставить штатный `set not null`. Для более старых версий не надо, это будет долго.

```
begin;
set local statement_timeout = '1s';
alter table measurement alter column created_at set not null;
alter table measurement 
     drop constraint measurement_created_at_not_null;
commit;
```

2. добавить ограничение check на некоторую дату в будущем. До этой даты мы обязуемся завершить миграцию. Либо запись новых данных остановится.

```
begin;
set local statement_timeout = '1s';
alter table measurement 
    add constraint measurement_old_partition 
    check(created_at < '2022-08-01') not valid;
commit;
alter table measurement validate constraint measurement_old_partition;
```

3. в назначенный день где-то до заданной в check ограничении даты делаем фокусы:

```
begin;
set local statement_timeout to '1s';
alter table measurement rename to measurement_olddata;
CREATE TABLE measurement (
     id bigint NOT NULL,
     created_at timestamp without time zone not null default now(), -- если вы не ставили родной set not null, то и здесь не должно быть not null
     data bigint NOT NULL
) PARTITION BY RANGE (created_at);
ALTER SEQUENCE measurement_id_seq OWNED BY public.measurement.id;
ALTER TABLE ONLY measurement ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('measurement_id_seq'::regclass);
alter table measurement attach partition measurement_olddata for values from (minvalue) to ('2022-08-01');
commit;
```

Всё, всем спасибо, все свободны =)

- если всё сделано верно - операция пройдёт за доли секунды и может выполняться на живом проекте
- если по таймауту через секунду вылетает поптыка переименования существующей таблицы - вам мешается какая-то транзакция. Смотрите, какие транзакции работают в этой базе и что творческое с ними можно сделать на время замены таблицы
- если по таймауту через секунду вылетают дальнейшие шаги - что-то сделали неверно. Проверьте, валидны ли check ограничения, не забыли ли про NULL, не перепутали ли даты в check и в attach partition.

---

Ладно, пояснения по магии выше:

`attach partition` может использовать валидные check constraint для того, чтобы пропускать проверку данных в таблице во время включения её в дерево партицирования. check constraint, в свою очередь, можно добавить без длительной блокировки, если сперва внести ограничение как not valid, а затем проверить его. validate constraint не блокирует чтение или запись в таблицу.

Поскольку в исходной табличке у нас был bigserial - но это не настоящий тип данных - в определении партицированной таблицы указываем реальный bigint и перепривязываем нижележащий сиквенс корректно к новой таблице.

Само собой, create table головы партицированной таблицы должен совпадать с определение существующей таблицы. `pg_dump -s` может помочь с получением create table выражения.

Проставленный в стратегических местах `statement_timeout` не позволит заблокировать таблицу на длительное время. В случае проблем - операция будет отменена и можно будет спокойно поразбираться, а что же пропустили.

Comment: Что-то еще не хватает все-таки, т.к. только эти констрейнты не помогают.

Comment: проверяйте тогда, чем ваша таблица отличается от показанной в ответе. Я при написании проверял, что требуемый для `partition constraint for table "measurement_olddata" is implied by existing constraints` codepath срабатывает. (видимый при `set client_min_messages to debug2;`)

Comment: Таблица много чем отличается, но суть понятна, спасибо. По констрейнтам я четко подогнал, как вы написали, но увы. Что имеете ввиду под "видимый при set client_min_messages to debug2;"?

Comment: на debug2 уровне вывода сообщений attach partition скажет вот такую фразу https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_14_4/src/backend/commands/tablecmds.c#L17049 если всё сделано верно. (ну, как видно из кода debug2 даже избыточен, debug1 бы хватило. Позабыл на что я его менял, ранее там был вообще info)